# Find rows in numpy.array (A) that are not in numpy.array(B)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working with two 2D numpy array that have ~20k and ~30k rows. Both A and B have 270 columns. I need to find the rows that are in A but not in B. I used the code below but it is too slow.

`B = np.array([x for x in A if x.tolist() not in A.tolist()])`

I need a fast version of this line of code. Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Please share a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use the mask off the linked question as `mask` and use it with `A[~mask]`.